# Why the list is on the next line?

Tags: html, css

My question is simple: why the items of the list are not on the same line with the logo, although I used inline-block as display mode?

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="header">

  <div class="logo"><span id="logo-text">Logo</span></div>

  <div class="menu">    
    <ol class="menu-list">
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>    
    </ol>  
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-list {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

**Online Editor:**

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/gsg/pen/MawEYw)

Comment: The float's are no longer necessarily if you are using `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use like this: **[Demo](http://codepen.io/kiranm/pen/NGqawW)**

```
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}
```

instead of this:

```
.menu-list {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block` to `.menu`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `div` is block element you need to add `disply:inline-block` or `float` in `.menu` div.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu{
  display:inline-block; /*add this class*/
}

.menu-list {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  
  <div class="logo"><span id="logo-text">Logo</span></div>
  
  <div class="menu">    
    <ol class="menu-list">
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>    
    </ol>  
  </div>
  
</div>
```